# agora-extension-virtual-background web assembly file

Tags: agora.io, agora

I've been wondering where I can find agora-extension-virtual-background web assembly file which can be passed to processor.init() function to speed up virtual background performance. That file is not included into the package, and looking for that file on the Internet hasn't been successful for me.
Any help will be appreciated.

Tried to find the needed file.